# Keycloak authorization menu in a pop-up tab

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keycloak

How can I make the login/registration window open in a browser popup on top of the current tab?

I'm using react + keycloak

I use the following method from the `@react-keycloak/web` library to open the authentication form: `await keycloak.login();`

Right now I have it open like this:
[image]

I want it to be like this:
[image]

Comment: You say in your title you want it in a new tab, but in your example it is a popup.